# custom signals in django

Tags: python, django

am having problem with django custom signals not being able to see signals across application. I made a simple call in my

core/signals.py

```
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import Signal
# Signal-emitting code... emits whenever a file upload is received
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

upload_recieved = Signal(providing_args=['data'])


def upload_received_handler(sender, data, **kwargs):
    print 'upload received handler'

print 'connecting signal'
upload_recieved.connect(upload_received_handler)
```

in core/models.py

```
import signals

[the model]
```

in blog/admin.py

```
from models import article, category, media 
from django.contrib import admin
from libs.shared.core.tasks import Create_Audit_Record
from libs.shared.core import signals



class ArticleModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        upload_recieved.send(sender=self, data='ddd')
        instance = form.save()
        return instance



admin.site.register(article, ArticleModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(category)
admin.site.register(media)
```

this is what I did, but am getting an error in the runtime unable to see upload_received function. any ideas?

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't imported the `upload_recieved` name into your admin.py.